# Adding an array to the session array in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, session

I am using a session based cart for a rails application where I am not allowed to use a database.

I have written this helper to create a the cart if it does not exist in my line_items controller.

```
def ensure_cart_exists
  session.push(Array(:cart)) unless session.include?(:cart)
end
```

But I get this error

```
undefined method `push' for #<ActionDispatch::Request::Session ...
```

The line of code works in the IRB when I try it on an array. Is there something I don't understand about the session array that prevents me from using it here?

Comment: Try this `(session[:cart] ||= []) << Array(:cart) unless session.include?(:cart)`

Comment: This seems to do the trick:
    ` (session.push Array :cart) unless session.include? [:cart]`

Comment: `session` is a hash, `session[:cart]` means `:cart` is a key to that hash which will be an `array` and to which you are assigning or pushing your array

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `session` is a hash like object, it does not act like an array. Do this instead:

```
def ensure_cart_exists
  session[:cart] ||= []
end
```

Answer (score 3):

A stylistic addition, but methods called things like ensure_something_exists are a bit of a red flag to me.

Rather than doing this:

```
ensure_cart_exists
session[:cart] << 'some data'
```

You should set up a method that will exposes the underlying item if it exists or creates the object if not. Then use that method for everything. So:

```
def cart
  session[:cart] ||= []
end

cart << 'some data'
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this as well, if you want a one liner:

`` (session[:cart] ||= []) << `some data` ``